# Why is an obvious improvement rejectable by a (novice) OP, outvoting supporting reviewers?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, new-users

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10950847), only to find it rejected later on. Still I think it was an improvement to:

- spell “Visual Basic” instead of a lower-case abbreviation (“vb”)
- use a typographic dash and apostrophe (`-` to `—` and `'` to `’`)
- remove quote markup, use bold emphasis on the actual question instead

The other two reviewers obviously thought the same way, approving the suggestion. The third reviewer (the OP) however, rejected it by choosing:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Allegedly, this decision was not based on factual grounds. I don’t want to imply the OP didn’t want his or her text to be tampered with, but I have no better guess, so I wonder:

Why are low-reputation, newly registered users able to reject edit suggestions? After all, that’s a delicate privilege. You need to earn 500 reputation to [access any review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), and even 2000 reputation to [review suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Can an OP (how?) always vote on suggestions for his/her question, regardless of experience, and does an OP’s veto thus outweigh two *supporting* votes?

If this is intentional, isn’t it undermining the concept of peer-review (through third parties) and the emphasis on community-edit above original authorship?

Comment: These are complaint-driven decisions.  A new user is much more likely to send an email to SE when he doesn't like his post "messed with".  Somebody that's been around for a while and have had edit suggestions rejected before just moves on with his life.  So giving a new user superpowers like this is one complaint less.  It would probably have worked differently if such a user posted about it at meta instead of asking for help from people that can't help.  But he can't.

Comment: As a personal thought on the edit, I learnt this stuff with vi, notepad and HTML 4 which really has no concept of typographics! (I know HTML 4 kinda did, but life really is too short for ASCII codes when you just want to write something, and pasting anything fancier than ' & - would generally just leave you with a WTF symbol - it probably has a better name ;) ) So I happen to prefer - and ' as typographically wrong as they might be. Had you changed a post of mine like that I likely would have rejected it too - though maybe gone back and changed the vb thing afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelB: It’s perfectly okay when everybody uses keyboard-means for quotes and dashes. However, to improve legibility and posts themselves, I think it’s always useful to change the characters, as long it’s not the only essence of an edit.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for this insight. It surely would’ve qualified as answer, especially if there’s an official statement that this is intended.

Comment: I would imagine it's also for the OP to be able to reject edits in the case where the editor misunderstood the OP and the clarification actually changes the question. You can always ping a mod if the OP is actively defacing their own posts (making it unreadable, totally changing the question, etc.) and rejecting edits to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose the OP didn't have the ability to reject the edit suggestion. Suppose this led to the edit suggestion being accepted. Now the OP would simply be able to roll back the edit. You wouldn't have gained anything by preventing the OP from unilaterally rejecting the suggestion.

That said:

> use a typographic dash and apostrophe (- to — and ' to ’)

It's not clear to me that that's an objective improvement, although there are certainly valid arguments in favour of it. Those characters are very difficult to type on most computers, which means they only rarely get used on SO, which means you're making the question look weird compared to the other questions on here.

Comment: Typography was the *least* important improvement, please consider the entire edit suggestion. I clarified an abbreviation and removed misplaced quote markup. I don’t think there’s any objection at all to any of those three things, so a rollback would’ve been as pointless as an outweighing veto, as long as there are no verifiable arguments against it.

Comment: @dakab I'm not saying I would've rejected your edit suggestion, or that it should've been rejected, merely that it's not as obviously correct as you suggest in your question. But your main question was why the OP was allowed to reject your edit suggestion, not whether the OP was right to reject your edit suggestion, and that's what I covered in my first paragraph.

Comment: @dakab: To be honest, if someone came to my question and reformatted the typography like that, I'd reject it *regardless* of whatever other good it had done. If I were feeling *generous*, I might adopt the good parts in a manual edit. But I certainly would not accept that kind of reformatting just because it contained other improvements.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You should elaborate on that, because I can’t imagine *any* reason for *such* a mind-set. You’d dismiss any other improvement along the way because… because of what? Someone using a finer style to improve legibility for the entire readership? Someone tampering with your CC-BY-SA contributions?

Comment: @dakab: "*Someone using a finer style to improve legibility for the entire readership?*" Because I don't believe that using "proper" dashes and quotation marks constitutes an improvement in the post's legibility. Neither way is objectively *unclear*, so the change is a no-op based on personal preference. Some people prefer **bold** for emphasis, others prefer *italics*.I do not believe that anyone should *force* their formatting preferences on others by editing their questions. Not unless there is an *objective* reason to do so.

Comment: @NicolBolas: If you think that way, you probably should consider reading a text book on that matter (or consulting a web designer). It’s not a matter of “personal reference”, at least not from a professional viewpoint. There’s no “enforcement”, but there’s always general [formatting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) Also note this was the most dispensable part of the edit.

Comment: @dakab You do realise that the formatting guidelines you link to use "in most but not *all* cases -- beware of ..." (using two - symbols rather than —) and "Here's" (using the ' symbol rather than ’), right?

Comment: @hvd: Does it change facts? Might that arise from the guidelines having been typed on a standard keyboard, simply using common substitutes? Would using the other licit characters make legibility worse? Most people won’t realize—but perceive—the differences.

Comment: @dakab I don't know what you mean by "change facts" so cannot answer that, other than perhaps by explaining my previous comment in some more detail. I'm trying very hard *not* to take any position of whether to use `-` or `—`, `'` or `’`, I merely called out on what I perceived as flawed logic: you were linking to the formatting guidelines in support of your point of view, but I'm not seeing anything in there that supports it. It doesn't mean your point of view is invalid or wrong, but does mean that if you want to convince someone who disagrees with you, you'll have to do better.

Answer (score 3):

The person rejected the edit was the OP himself – the *only* one who can make this One Vote decision. You will have to ask him personally. Some people don't like others to touch their question.

Note that this little snippet of information appears to be missing from the Help Center, under:

> Two (three on Stack Overflow) accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it.

Had the OP not straight out rejected your edit, it would most likely have gone through.

---

Although there is no need to bold "the" question for emphasis. The blockquoting was inappropriate and you were right to remove it – but that's all.

That said: *thank you for editing*!
<sup>And being a graphic designer myself: **thank you** for using appropriate quotes and em-dashes!</sup>

Comment: Have I understood correctly that you think that the above mentioned text snippet would be a valuable addition to the Help Center? And equally important: How do I ask him personally?

Comment: @dakab: I scanned the description of approving/rejecting edits and could not find anything referring to the OP's "final vote". So yes, this may need to be added. As for asking the OP, that was half-joking. All you *could* do is leave a (public!) comment under his post – and run the risk of having it removed by someone else, as it's not really appropriate use of the Comments feature. Using my >2K Super Editing Powers, I incorporated your suggestions; I strongly suggest leaving it at this and move on.